# What is the main difference between RSS, RPS and RFS?

Tags: linux, performance, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

As known, there are: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt

- RSS: Receive Side Scaling
- RPS: Receive Packet Steering
- RFS: Receive Flow Steering

Does it meant that:

- RSS - allows us to use many CPU-Cores to process Soft-irq from Ethernet (one CPU-Core for each Ethernet queue)
- RPS - allows us to process Soft-irq for all packets from one the same connection on one and the same CPU-Core
- RFS - allows us to process Soft-irq for all packets from one the same connection on one and the same CPU-Core on which thread of our Application procces this connection

Is that correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quotes are from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt.

- RSS: Receive Side Scaling - is hardware implemented and hashes some bytes of packets ("hash function over the network and/or transport layer headers-- for example, a 4-tuple hash over IP addresses and TCP ports of a packet"). Implementations are different, some may not filter most useful bytes or may be limited in other ways. This filtering and queue distribution is fast (only several additional cycles are needed in hw to classify packet), but not portable between some network cards or can't be used with tunneled packets or some rare protocols. And sometimes your hardware have no support of number of queues enough to get one queue per logical CPU core.

> RSS should be enabled when latency is a concern or whenever receive
>   interrupt processing forms a bottleneck. Spreading load between CPUs
>   decreases queue length.

- Receive Packet Steering (RPS) "is logically a software implementation of
  RSS. Being in software, it is necessarily called later in the datapath.". So, this is software alternative to hardware RSS (still parses some bytes to hash them into queue id), when you use hardware without RSS or want to classify based on more complex rule than hw can or have protocol which can't be parsed in HW RSS classifier. But with RPS more CPU resources are used and there is additional inter-CPU traffic.

> RPS has some advantages over RSS: 1) it can be used with any NIC,
>   2) software filters can easily be added to hash over new protocols,
>   3) it does not increase hardware device interrupt rate (although it does
>   introduce inter-processor interrupts (IPIs)).

- RFS: Receive Flow Steering is like RSS (software mechanism with more CPU overhead), but it not just hashing into pseudo-random queue id, but takes "into account application locality." (so, packet processing will probably be faster due to good locality). Queues are tracked to be more local to the thread which will process received data, and packets are delivered to correct CPU core.

> The goal of RFS is to increase datacache hitrate by steering
>   kernel processing of packets to the CPU where the application thread
>   consuming the packet is running. RFS relies on the same RPS mechanisms
>   to enqueue packets onto the backlog of another CPU and to wake up that
>   CPU. ... In RFS, packets are not forwarded directly by the value of their hash,
>   but the hash is used as index into a flow lookup table. This table maps
>   flows to the CPUs where those flows are being processed.

- Accelerated RFS - RFS with hw support. (Check your network driver for `ndo_rx_flow_steer`) "Accelerated RFS is to RFS what RSS is to RPS: a hardware-accelerated load balancing mechanism that uses soft state to steer flows based on where the application thread consuming the packets of each flow is running.".

---

Similar method for packet transmitting (but packet is already generated and ready to be send, just select best queue to send it with - and to easier post-processing like freeing skb)

- XPS: Transmit Packet Steering: "a mapping from CPU to hardware queue(s) is
  recorded. The goal of this mapping is usually to assign queues
  exclusively to a subset of CPUs, where the transmit completions for
  these queues are processed on a CPU within this set"

Answer (score 5):

osgx's answer covers the main differences, but it is important to point out that it is also possible to use RSS and RPS in unison.

RSS controls the selected HW queue for receiving a stream of packets. Once certain conditions are met, an interrupt would be issued to the SW. The interrupt handler, which is defined by the NIC's driver, would be the SW starting point for processing received packets. The code there would poll the packets from the relevant receive queue, might perform initial processing and then move the packets for higher level protocol processing.

At this point RPS mechanism might be used, if configured. The driver calls netif_receive_skb(), which (eventually) will check for RPS configuration. If exists it would enqueue the SKB for continuing processing on the selected CPU:

```
int netif_receive_skb(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        ...
        return netif_receive_skb_internal(skb);
}

static int netif_receive_skb_internal(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        ...
                int cpu = get_rps_cpu(skb->dev, skb, &rflow);

                if (cpu >= 0) {
                        ret = enqueue_to_backlog(skb, cpu, &rflow->last_qtail);
                        rcu_read_unlock();
                        return ret;
                }
        ...
}
```

In some scenarios, it would be smart to use RSS and RPS together in order to avoid CPU utilization bottlenecks on the receiving side. A good example is IPoIB (IP over Infiniband). Without diving into too many details, IPoIB has a mode which can only open a single channel. This means all the incoming traffic would be handled by a single core. By properly configuring RPS, some of the processing load can be shared by multiple cores, which dramatically improves performance for this scenario.

Since transmitting was mentioned, it worth noting that packet transmission, which results from the receiving process (ACKs, forwarding), would be processed from the same core selected by netif_receive_skb().

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I.e. **if RPS is on**, then Soft-IRQ will be enqueued to backlog and may be **handled on remote CPU Core** http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.1/source/net/core/dev.c#L3742 But **if RPS is off**, then packet will processed immediately **on the same CPU-Core** by using `__netif_receive_skb() {... __netif_receive_skb_core() ...}` http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.1/source/net/core/dev.c#L4417   Does it mean "IPoIB  can only open a single channel", that IPoIB has only 1 rx-queue or something else? So RSS used to distribute Soft-IRQs across many CPU-Cores, isn't it?

Comment: IPoIB has two operation mode - Datagram and Connected. When running in Connected mode only one channel is used, so yes only one RX queue. Which do you mean on the last line? RSS or RPS? Both use interrupts.

Comment: So main question, if both RSS and RPS uses Soft-IRQ, then why do we need for RSS, if we can use RPS for the same thing? Why not only RPS? Also is we have only one hardware NIC-rx-queue, then why do we need for RSS? As I know, RSS used only if NIC-rx-queues more than 1, isn't it? https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt "Packets for each flow are **steered to a separate receive
queue**, which in turn can be processed by separate CPUs. This mechanism is generally **known as Receive-side Scalingв (RSS).**"

Comment: I gave IPoIB as an example, but yes in this scenario RSS is enabled but can't do anything with a single RX queue. Other scenarios, such as IP forwarding, may benefit as well. Two rules of thumb for using both would be (1) RX queues < number of cores and (2) processing both interrupt handler and higher level protocol processing on the same core create a CPU bottleneck.

Comment: Regarding why use RSS at all, please see the code snippet in my answer. The netif_receive_skb() function is much "higher" in the call stack compared to the interrupt handler, meaning without RSS there would be a bunch of code executing on a single CPU for all incoming streams. This might cause a CPU bottleneck. If you wish to understand it better, I suggest creating a [flame-graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) of the RX call stack and see the difference between each decision point for changing CPU

Comment: Thank you! I.e. if required to do IP forwarding, then using both RSS and RPS allows to use different CPU-Cores for Soft-IRQ and `netif_receive_skb()`, and allows to use more CPU-Cores.

Comment: **1. if we use RSS without RPS**, then for 1 rx-queue **we can occupy all CPU-Cores** `echo FFFFFFFF >/proc/irq/[eth-queue-irq]/smp_affinity`. **2. if we use RPS without RSS then we too can occupy all CPU-Cores** `echo FFFFFFFF > /sys/class/net/eth0/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus`. **3. if we use RSS with RPS, then we can occupy all CPU-Cores**, but the same packet will be processed on different Cores, it will add overhead of sending a packet between CPU-Cores - and it increases latency and may decreses throughput - due to cost of this overhead.

Comment: I'm sorry but (1) isn't 100% correct. RSS maps streams to queues. When you have a single queue, all streams would be mapped to it.the smp_affinity maps the interrupt assigned to this queue to CPU cores, but there's no reason to select different cores even if you allow all available cores to be selected. you can run a quick test (don't forget to disable irqbalancer) and see that all interrupts would be handled on the same core (for me it was always core #0). (2) is correct. (3) is also correct so you have to be careful when using this as there's a tradeoff here.